# How to target a lower language level in Java

Tags: java, maven, lambda, java-8

I maintain a Java [tutorial application](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaconcurrenta/) written in Java, that demonstrates features of Java 6, 7, and 8. Each tutorial screen is loaded dynamically by Class.forName as needed. The Java 7 classes need to use Java 7 constructs, and the Java 8 classes need to use Lambdas and Date/Time API.

I would like this to be accessible to users of all three of those language levels, just that if they are on Java 6 we would not load up the Java 7 or 8 classes, and if on 7 we would not load the Java 8 classes.

We would dynamically determine the runtime level and disregard higher levels, loading only the relevant classes by Class.forName(). Obviously users with Java 6 or 7 would not be able to execute code with a magic number of 8. So I would like to target an earlier Java release in the build.

In other words, I would like to set source to 1.8 and target to 1.6

However Maven (and Javac) prevent me from specifying a target lower than the source.

Is there any other way?

I have done this in the past with JavaFX code for Android, where I was able to build JavaFX 8 code using Lambdas, but then deploy it to current Android versions. But in that case, there was a special SDK that handled the lambdas and built to Java 7.

Is there any way to do that with standard Java 8?

Comment: The only option you have is `-source 1.1 -target 1.0` In every other case, they have to be the same.

Comment: You need to build a jar for each version and another which combines them.

Comment: :( I was afraid you would say that

Comment: Worth checking it's really needed before going down that road. ;)

Comment: If someone can turn this into an answer I can check it off as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you have is -source 1.1 -target 1.0 In every other case, they have to be the same

You need to build a jar for each version and another which combines them.

Comment: I just wonder how JavaFX 8 let's you use Lambdas https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html based on https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda and deploy them to earlier Android versions. Also, Spring 4 is compatible with Java 6u18 and higher, but it supports Java 8. How'd they do that?

Comment: @VictorGrazi I believe Android doesn't run byte code, but code translated from it.  In this translation you can lift the restriction or translate it in any number of ways.

Comment: @VictorGrazi I don't know anything about Spring 4. ;)

Comment: @Victor Grazi: what do you think is so special about Spring being compatible with Java 6 while also supporting Java 8? All Java versions are compatible to their predecessors. That’s why I don’t understand why “You need to build a jar for each version” solves your problem, or maybe what’s your problem actually is. Code compiled with `-source 1.6 -target 1.6` will, of course, run on 1.7 and 1.8 as well. Same for `-source 1.7 -target 1.7` which will run on 1.8. And, of course, you can add classes compiled for different targets into one Jar file, if you wish.

Comment: @Holger I would have assumed that since Spring 4 exploits Java 8, it is written using Java 8 syntax. Which would imply that it is using source=target=8. Which implies that it would not run in earlier versions, unless it were compiled with source=8 target=6. Anyway, I guess the answer is that my original instinct was wrong, and that they use an earlier version of java source to code Spring

Comment: Which version of *javac* supports `-source 1.1 -target 1.0`? Does it actually work for you? I couldn't get it to work with anything between 1.3 and 1.8. Here is what I've tried: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54620554

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make 3 different jars, one for each version where the later version include more of your code examples.  (on the bright side, you just have to recompile the the java 6 and 7 code multiple times)

for each jar set the `-target` code to 6, 7 or 8 respectively.  You can optionally also use `-source` parameter and set it to the same value but I don't think you need to unless you are worried you accidentally put in later language features.